# Return a Task<T> from a method that passes its result to an Action<T> parameter

Tags: c#, .net, task, action

I have a service I need to connect to that passes data back through an action like this:

```
public Guid UpdateEntities<T>(Action<EntitiesChangedResponse<T>> onResponse, IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    //Get some data
    onResponse.Invoke(response);
{
```

Existing code would call the service as follows:

```
Guid requestId = _productService.UpdateEntities<Product>(x => OnEntitiesUpdated(x), new List<Product> { updateProduct1, updateProduct2 });
```

And the callback would do something with the result at some point in the future:

```
private void OnEntitiesUpdated<T>(EntitiesChangedResponse<T> response)
{
    //Do something with the result
}
```

I'm try to integrate it with a task based signal R hub so need to return the operation as a typed task, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to achieve this (I'm quite new to tasks so please tell me if this is daft).

It would look something like this:

```
public Task<EntitiesChangedResponse<Product>> UpdateProducts(List<Product> products)
{
    //Somehow wrap this in a task
    Task<EntitiesChangedResponse<Product>> result = New Task<EntitiesChangedResponse<Product>>( call the product service );

    return result;
}
```

Any help appreciated. It is hurting my head.

Comment: Don't spam tags! This is not C!

Comment: @Olaf Sorry it was a typo. First ever question. Be gentle.

Comment: Typically you'd use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` if you have some asynchronous event or callback based API that you want to adapt to using Tasks, but it doesn't look like UpdateEntities is actually asynchronous. Perhaps you could to use `Task.Run` to move the operation onto another thread.

Comment: @mikez Cheers mate. UpdateEntities is indeed asycnronous. Underneath its calling some easynetq stuff (rabbitmq library). So this comment pushed me in the write direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a bridge between "callback" API and task based API you can use `TaskCompletionSource`

```
    public Task<EntitiesChangedResponse<Product>> UpdateProducts(List<Product> products)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<EntitiesChangedResponse<Product>>();

        _productService.UpdateEntities<Product>(response => tcs.SetResult(response), new List<Product> { updateProduct1, updateProduct2 });

        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Comment: Note that this will block the calling thread and I don't think that this is the point.

Comment: @Eyal Perry It seems that "UpdateEntities" method is asynchronous. Based on "_And the callback would do something with the result at some point in the future_". So calling tread will not be blocked

Comment: Not sure mate, since this guy claims to be new to tasks.. Otherwise- your solution is exactly what is needed.

Comment: @EyalPerry Conversely using a non-UI Thread could also cause problem, assuming this is a UI program. You can't tell. My only issue with this answer is that you could just use `Task.FromResult()` for the same effect.

Comment: @Aron True. skipped my mind there. See my answer to this post.

Comment: @Aron Actually you can't because the result is provided by the callback. At least currently. Not sure if "service" api can be changed

Comment: Brilliant. Cheer Aleksey, that is exactly what I need. The task is fired when the result comes back with the response -  so yes should have been more clear that the result is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at the following method:

```
 public Task<EntitiesChangedResponse<T>> UpdateEntities<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities)
 {
    var updateTask = Task.Run(()=>
    {
        //return data from this lambda expression
    });

    return updateTask;
 }
```

This starts and returns a task which does your work.

(If you really need the GUID you can return a Tuple or any DTO containing both).

You now have a couple of options to consume this task, here's one:

```
private Task async UpdateEntitiesAsync<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    try
    {
        EntitiesChangedResponse<T> response = await UpdateEntities(entities);
        //asynchronous callback implementation code can go here
    }
    catch(AggregateException ex)
    {
      //handle a thrown exception
    }
}
```

Do note:

1)The execution continues past the 'await' statement once the task completes and will execute the following LOC.

2) if the task faults (throws an exception) the LOC past the await block will not execute and the catch clause will execute instead.

3) Calling the UpdateEntitiesAsync method does not block the calling thread. the execution immediately returns to the caller once the await statement is hit.

4) You can await the task returned from the async method as well since it (implicitly) returns a task which finishes once this method executes in full, making this method awaitable in itself, if such a need arises.

Alternatively, you can have this method return void, if you do not really care about when it completes.

5) If you do not catch the exception in this method, know that the task returned from the async method will fault, and must be handled somewhere up the invocation chain.

You can do this by either awaiting the task, accessing the Exception property, or invoking the Wait method of the task.

6) The Async postfix in the method's name is merely a naming convention, applied so that client code is aware of the method's asynchronous nature.

Comment: thanks. I wasn't clear that UpdateEntities returns immediately with the requestId and that response is asynchronous on the callback OnEntitiesUpdated. Have given you an upvote anyway.